# Where is the correct location for Dask Worker configuration file and the Dask Scheduler configuration file?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am attempting to find the correct location of Dask configuration files. I have a number of questions related to configuring Dask.

```
$ dask-worker --version
dask-worker, version 2.3.2
```

**Do the Dask Worker and Dask Scheduler share the same configuration file or do they use different configuration files?**

I am unclear if there are configuration variables that are specific to Dask Worker and Dask Scheduler. Is there a list of the valid configuration variables for Dask Worker and Dask Scheduler?

**Where are the correct locations of the Dask Worker and Dask Scheduler configuration files?**

I have found three different configuration files across my system and the Dask documentation:

1. `~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml`
2. `~/.config/dask/dask.yaml`
3. `~/.dask/config.yaml`

On my Dask Worker and Dask Scheduler machines, I find a file located at `~/.config/dask/dask.yaml` which does not contain much information. I am not sure what should go into this file or if/where it is ever called by the Dask library.

I also see a file at `~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml` that contains much more information. This looks more like the configuration I was expecting. I can see that these configuration are also loaded by Dask in [distributed/config.py](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/adf247c15c32831b10c76a163cf0f769c4339483/distributed/config.py)

A third file (`~/.dask/config.yaml`) makes an appearance in the [documentation](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html#user-wide-configuration). To quote the documentation:

> Dask accepts some configuration options in a configuration file, which by default is a .dask/config.yaml file located in your home directory.

I do not see this file on my system. Am I responsible for creating this configuration file? I never see this file referenced in the repository. Why does the documentation differ from the source code?

**Can I print a list of all active configuration variables for both the Worker and the Scheduler?**

Is there a way, either on the command line or in Python, where I can inspect the active configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For documentation on Dask's configuation system please see https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html

That page says:

Configuration is specified in one of the following ways:

- YAML files in `~/.config/dask/` or `/etc/dask/`
- Environment variables like `DASK_DISTRIBUTED__SCHEDULER__WORK_STEALING=True`
- Default settings within sub-libraries

I've removed the page that you were looking at in this PR: https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/3038

Comment: Thanks for submitting the PR and answering my question @MRocklin, I appreciate it. 

You mention a specific configuration that is in fact the reason for my question, worker stealing configuration.

There are two worker stealing configurations I have encountered: `DASK_DISTRIBUTED__SCHEDULER__WORK_STEALING` and `DASK_WORK_STEALING`

Should I use both configuration variables and do I need to pass both of them as environment variables on both my scheduler and worker machines?

It would be really nice to see a list of all of the possible configurations with an explanation of what they do.

Comment: All possible configuration options are listed in the documentation listed in the answer.  You will need to have the configuration available on every machine that is running Dask code.  Dask will not transfer your configuration automatically (in practice it might vary between machines, so we can't assume homogeneity).

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt reply.